# is it possible to impose speed limit to certain device connected to my hotspot?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, termux

I have several devices connected to my android hotspot and would like to rate limit certain device from hogging the bandwidth too much. Phone is already rooted, and i've tried using built-in 'tc' program (followed the guide from here https://serverfault.com/questions/191560/how-can-i-do-traffic-shaping-in-linux-by-ip) from android terminal with no avail.

Is it even possible to do such thing?

Comment: `tc` is the perfect tool for this purpose, and it works on Android. I've experimented with it in past. But IIRC I used my own custom built binary.